# Get Excel sheet object under the mouse

Tags: excel, vba, mouse

Is there any way to get the object under the mouse in Excel sheet (not in the form).

The reason is that I have bunch of charts and some shapes on them. When I click the shape on the specific chart, macro is launched, doing some stuff to the current chart (ActiveChart). However, this works only if chart is activated prior to clicking shape on it. If you click shape without activating the chart, ActiveChart is Nothing.

So, I need some way to get the object/chart/cell which is under the mouse.

Sheet and Book don't have click or mousemove event. Setting the one on all charts I have also have the same problem as described.

I didn't also figure out how to find out which shape was clicked (since _Click macro doesn't have any parameters). E

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try making all of your shape names unique, and include the chart name in each.

Then you can use Application.Caller within the macro handling the click to get the shape name. From that, you can parse out the chart name.

Tim

Comment: I have many charts on the sheet. Charts can be turned on or off. Thanks for Application.Caller note. I can get the range of rectangle clicked and iterate over charts to find which chart range it belongs.  I am not sure what you mean with :  From that, you can parse out the chart name but I will look into it.

Comment: For shapes contained in charts (I'm assuming that's the case here) the usual "unique name" constraint doesn't seem to apply, so you can't be sure from the clicked shape's name exactly what chart it's on.  That's why I suggested naming your shapes (eg) "Chart1_ShapeName1".

Comment: Excel doesn't allow you to name shapes. However, I managed to change the name via VBA code and did it that way. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a chart WILL activate its parent sheet and book. So you could use something like
    `ActiveSheet.Charts(0)` 
if you only have 1 chart per sheet.
To find out what was clicked, you could have the caller provide its name/id either as an argument (might not be usable here) or by setting a global variable (not too nice but usable in a single user/single process context).

Comment: Not feasible. First, chart is NOT activated ever. I have more then 1 chart (any number actually). To set global variable is not pracitcal as each chart has a button so I would need 1 sub for each, instead like now where I assign each click handler to the same subroutine.